# How do i add a line break after display for in vb.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I want to add a line break after the `@html.DisplayFor` in mvc. I am using this in `@code` and `End Code`. So it is not permitting me to add a `<br>` after `DisplayFor`. I cannot use `<li>` either.

```
 @Code
Each i As ACDC In 
Model.Documentation.Active.AcceptableDocuments        
@Html.SLCheckBox("noticeofaction", False) 
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(x) i.Value)          
Next
End Code
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Code
    Each i As ACDC In Model.Documentation.Active.AcceptableDocuments
        @Html.SLCheckBox("noticeofaction", False)
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(x) i.Value)
        @Html.Raw("<br/>")
    Next
End Code
```

Comment: This outputs nothing! (you should try your code first)

Comment: It works on C#, so I'm pretty sure the VB syntax isn't too different from this.

Comment: It does not (and clearly you still have not bothered to test it) The `Display()` method renders the value of the property named in the 1st parameter, and since OP does not (and cannot) have a property named `<br />` then it outputs nothing

Comment: @StephenMuecke `Html.Display("something")` creates a label with `id="something"` attribute, right? I think OP should build custom HTML helper which inserts `<br />` tag at the end of passed string.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, No it does not `@Html.Display()` just outputs text - it does not generate a html tag